# opencv C++ Finding contours and drawing rectangles around them and displaying coordinates

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

How can I draw bounding rectangle for more than one contours in a binary image and display their coordinates in original image??I am using opencv with C++ platform

Comment: Try to google something, read OpenCV's official documentation, try something on your own first

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, use `findContours` to get your contours, then use `boundingRect` to generate a bounding box for each contour, then draw each bounding box to your original image using the `rectangle` function.

If you're looking for an example, the OpenCV documentation already has it [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html)